# Absolutely positioned child element gets clipped during animation of parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a box that grows on hover.
The box has a thumbnail inside it that is `position:absolute` and bigger than the parent box.

When I animate the width or height of the parent container, the thumbnail gets cropped to the size of the parent, but only during the animation.

See here for a simple demo (tested in chrome/safari/ff on mac):
http://jsfiddle.net/Q2BPx/3/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this is expected as jquery will set `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden` during animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know that you are doing anything "wrong" per se.

When the animate method is running jQuery uses inline style to set the width for each frame of the animation. It also adds the style "overflow: hidden" into the inline style.

You can hack the css of expander by adding:     overflow: visible !important;

This will prevent the inline overflow: hidden from making your thumbnail being cropped.

But, you might want to look into the jQuery code to see why animate is using the overflow setting.

Or, at least test your page to make sure you have not introduced an anomaly by using the overflow: visible !important;

Comment: Thanks. Wow, that seems like a bug in jQuery. I'm sure they have a reason for doing it but it's not documented in the code. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L214