# animating a container that has absolutely positioned children overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am sliding a container that is 100% width and 100% height up while another one goes out the screen for navigation, but my absolute positioned items become visible whenever the animation starts. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085206/jquery-animate-element-that-has-children-absolutely-positioned-outside-it-bl) question's first answer says that there's a line of code that makes overflow, hidden, but it seems to not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hash = location.hash;
  console.log(hash);
  $(window).on("hashchange",function(){
    hash=hash?hash:"#page1";
    $(hash)
    //I have tried adding
    //.css("overflow","hidden");
    .animate({height:"hide"});
    hash = location.hash
    $(hash)
    //I have tried adding
    //.css("overflow","hidden");
    .animate({height:"show"});
  });
  hash?$(hash).toggleClass("page-active"):$("#page1").toggleClass("page-active");
});
```

here a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eL0fd1z3/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using fixed position for your anchor thus they are positioned relatively to the browser. Instead use `position:absolute`  and make their parent `position:relative` so they become positioned relatively to their container and smoothly appear with their container

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hash = location.hash;
  $(window).on("hashchange", function() {
    hash = hash ? hash : "#page1";
    $(hash)
      //I have tried adding
      //.css("overflow","hidden");
      .animate({
        height: "hide"
      });
    hash = location.hash
    $(hash)
      //I have tried adding
      //.css("overflow","hidden");
      .animate({
        height: "show"
      });
  });
  hash ? $(hash).toggleClass("page-active") : $("#page1").toggleClass("page-active");
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
}

.page1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.page2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lime;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.page-active {
  display: block;
}

a {
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="page1" id="page1">
    hello
    <a href="#page2">go to page2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="page2" id="page2">
    hi
    <a href="#page1">go to page1</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: yeah oops, I forgot I switched it to position:fixed when I was trying stuff out, but I thought my bigger containers had position:fixed but I guess not, that should fix it